# UITableViewCell height not adjusting until user scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to fill the cell.textLabel with text. That text varies in the number of lines per object in the array, and as such the cell needs to adjust in height. The cell doesn't adjust in height until the user scrolls through the list.

Here in the code.

Image of IB [image]

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];


      cell.textLabel.text = [kanyeLines objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText =[kanyeLines objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:cellText
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: cellFont
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];

    return rect.size.height + 20;
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq Yes I am.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't implement *heightForRow...` or `estimatedHeightForRow...`.

Comment: Its implemented. You can see it in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd accidentally set the datasource twice for the table instead of setting a delegate.